# ¿Cómo preparar un Proyecto con dos versiones (lite/pro) de una App en Android-Studio usando flavors?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Estoy a punto de iniciar una aplicación para Android quiero sacar dos versiones una *lite* y otra *pro*.

Las dos versiones tendrán código compartido y dependiendo si es la *pro* tendrá opciones extras.

Más o menos he leído algo de que se debe hacer con *flavors* pero soy muy nuevo en el mundo de desarrollo en Android.

Comment: respecto a lo que explican quisiera hacer una consulta.. al crear la lite y la pro (APK) supongamos tengo la lite instalada al instalar la pro me sobre-escribe la lite o se instala una nueva app con la extencion .pro tengo esa duda porque he probado y se me instalan dos apps me gustaria saber como logar que se sobre escriba la lite gracias

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No se si usted tiene alguna duda en concreto o sobre parte de proceso le dejo esto espero ayude (basado en AS):

Bien pulsamos <kbd>F4</kbd> o `Android view` `app` >> `Open Module Settings`, para usar <kbd>F4</kbd> tienes que tener selecionado `app`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

creamos los nombres en este caso `lite` y `pro` ect con el <kbd>+</kbd> que aparece en la imagen.

Puede usar los campos que aparecen al añadir su sabor y rellernarlos con los datos que usted necesite, `application id`, `code`, `name`, `Sdk`

Despues puedes mirar tu `build gradle file` y tendras algo similar a esto:

```
productFlavors {
        pro {
        }
        lite {
        }
    }
```

---

Ahora crear las carpetas en donde pondremos el codigo dependendiente de cada uno de los sabores, estas carpetas las pones dentro de `src` en `view mode Project` y (espero acordarme de poner una foto de esto) y deben tener el mismo nombre usado al crear los sabores/flavors, el resto de codigo compartido/comun seguira poniendo/ubicando dentro de `main` para esta vista, y el que es unico para cada sabor puedes ver un ejemplo para un drawable en la imagen, crear el directorio basado en la estructura que maneja AS como ves `res/drawable/imagen.png` es como si lo quisieras crear en main para tu aplicacion "normal" pero ahora esta dentro del sabor, espero se entienda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fijese que esta en la `view project` no en la `Android`.

Notas: puedes ver que se a marcado el directorio `res` en el sabor lite, porque es ese el que esta selecionado en el `variants` que te dejare una imagen.

---

Para cambiar de sabor en borde de AS suele estar el boton `Build Variants` ahi podemos establecerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Para crear codigo para cada variants es similar a el ejemplo de las imagenes, se crearia dentro del directorio similar al que se usa en `main` pero como lo indicado en las imagenes anteriormente:

```
package com.app.mi.android.flavors/lite;  

public class ClaseStaticaDependiente {  

    public static String get() {  
        return "esta es una llamada a el sabor/lite";  
    }  
}
```

y para llamarlo seria algo similar a esto, pues al estar seleccionado un sabor u otro se buscara en el directorio que se le indique:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    //buscaria una clase que tendria en los directorios para cada sabor
    //y selecionaria la que corresponda esta seria una clase por ejemplo
    //que retornara un String diferente para cada sabor  
    Log.d("Flavors",ClaseStaticaDependiente.get());  
}
```

Para cada sabor puede poner algo asi en el `module settings` correspondiente a cada sabor ejemplo:

```
applicationId com.app.mi.android.lite
```

---

Adicional: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Answer (score 3):

Que tal, realmente no hay que preparar Android Studio para preparar versiones lite o pro de tu app.
Es a tu aplicacion (proyecto) lo que realmente debes preparar, creo que la pregunta está mal formulada.
En todo caso, la configuración de versiones o buildVariants se realiza mendiante Gradle (incluso existe un wizard), cuando se configuran sabores de una app se debe distribuir el contenido (res/, src/, etc.) que las hace ser diferentes en su directorio correspondiente. Ya que cuando defines un flavor para tu app, se creará un directorio específico para el.

En tu fichero /app/build.gradle deberás tener algo similar a esto

```
productFlavors {
    demoConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        applicationId 'com.my.appname'
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.demo.20150716"
    }
    productionConfig {
    }
}
```

en donde se pueden apreciar las 2 versiones que se tienen del app (demoConfig y productionConfig)

A nivel de directorios vas a ver algo como esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para la versión demoConfig, el código, los recursos, xml y demás deberás colocarlos en la carpeta generada para el buildVariant y en la carpeta main está el código (y recursos) productivo (sin limitaciones).

Cuando vayas a distribuir las aplicaciones, al momento de generar el apk es donde deberás indicar que tipo de APK quieres generar, el lite o el pro.

Aquí lo explican muy bien [http://developer.android.com/](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) y acá [algo en español](http://sglora.com/tutorial-de-gradle-ii/)

Espero te guíe, saludos,

Comment: "cuando se configuran sabores de una app" :D

Comment: Ahahaha algunas cosas suenan mejor en inglés :)

Answer (score 3):

Ciertamente la configuración para Product Flavors te puede ayudar, la documentación en inglés se encuentra aquí [**Configuring Gradle Builds**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html), pero te escribo como sería tu `build.gradle` para configurar estos 2 flavors, suponiendo que las 2 tienen las mismas dependencias:

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    productFlavors {
        apppro{
            applicationId "com.paquete.apppro"
            manifestPlaceholders = [ appName:"mi app Pro"]
        }
        applite{
            applicationId "com.paquete.applite"
            manifestPlaceholders = [ appName:"mi app Lite"]
        }
    }

    configurations {
        appproDebugCompile
        appproReleaseCompile
        appliteDebugCompile
        appliteReleaseCompile
    }
}
```

Recuerda crear los directorios donde se contendrán las versiones a generar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En realidad es muy sencillo, desgraciadamente no encontré tutoriales en español pero en este tutorial puedes ver en el punto 5.3 mediante las imágenes lo que te comento:
[5.3. Defining product flavors in your Gradle build file](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html#d26617e144)